# Java toString printing error with a linkedlist using objects

Tags: java, io, reference, linked-list

I'll try to make this as simple as possible.
I have a class of Pet objects:

```
public class Pet {
private String name;
private int treats;
private Coordinate coor;
}
```

Note that `coor` is just an object that contains 2 floats, longitude and latitude.

In my executable class I call my PetList(a linkedlist) class' printAll() function.

```
PetList List = new PetList();
... // adding nodes to my linkedlist etc.
...
List.printAll();
```

In my printAll() function I call my toString function within my Pet class:

```
public void printAll() {
    LinkNode temp = first;
    while(temp != null) {
        System.out.print(toString());
        System.out.println();
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```

In my toString() function, I create a StringBuilder:

```
// Most of this appending is formatting
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(name);
    // sb.append("{");
    sb.append(treats);
    // sb.append("} ");
    //if(coor.getLatitude() >= 0) {
    //    sb.append("+");
    //}
    sb.append(coor.getLatitude());
    // sb.append(" ");
    //if(coor.getLongitude() >= 0) {
    //    sb.append("+");
    //}
    sb.append(coor.getLongitude());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm reading input until EOF:

```
add 3.0 3.0 Three // add(adds a node) with 2 floats (longitude & latitude) and Three(a name)
add 2.0 2.0 Two
add 1.0 1.0 One
```

But when I call print (which calls printAll()) I get this:

```
add 3.0 3.0 Three
add 2.0 2.0 Two
add 1.0 1.0 One
print
PetList@33909752
PetList@33909752
PetList@33909752
```

But I want this to happen:

```
add 3.0 3.0 Three
add 2.0 2.0 Two
add 1.0 1.0 One
print
One{0} +1.0, +1.0
Two{0} +2.0, +2.0
Three{0} +3.0, +3.0
```

I am not sure, but am I getting a reference instead of any actual data? Is it due to anything in the code I have shown? Or is it somewhere else? Any help is appreciated thanks!

EDIT:

```
Here is the beginning of my PetList class:
public class PetList {
    protected class LinkNode {
        protected LinkNode next;
        protected LinkNode prev;
        protected Pet animal;

        public LinkNode() {
            next = prev = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is how I call the toString function now:

```
//public void printAll() {
 //  LinkNode temp = first;
 //   while(temp != null) {
        System.out.print(animal.toString());
 //       System.out.println();
 //       temp = temp.next;
 //   }
//}
```

And here is the error I am getting when trying to compile:

```
PetList.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.print(animal.toString());
                             ^
  symbol:   variable animal
  location: class PetList
```

Comment: Does your PetList class have its own toString() method? Right now it is using the Object.toString() method.

Comment: Oh my goodness it doesn't so I haven't been calling the toString method this entire time lol

Comment: Hmm in my PetList class I have a `protected Pet animal;` but when I add animal to my toString call it gives me an error. Modified call: `System.out.print(animal.toString());` Error: `./PetList.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.print(animal.toString());`

Comment: @Jason any ideas?

Comment: An update with a snippet above might help.

Comment: @Jason I added some more detail at the end after EDIT

Comment: Did you import the `java.util` package in the beginning of this `.java` file???

Comment: Upload a code or link to pastebin where we can test and run

Comment: @progyammer I am not using the java.util.LinkedList collection I am creating my own linkedlist.

Comment: I know that you're creating your custom LL. I was looking for something else. Anyway, I don't need to know that now.

Comment: What context is the printout taking placed in? Is there another method replacing the one that has been commented out, or is node floating outside a method?

Comment: Here is all of my code: https://pastebin.com/1PNxjREM

Comment: I can see that you know how to get `animal` correctly because you already did it once.  You just didn't do it right the second time.

Comment: Do I need to write `animal = new Pet();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest code snippet:

```
        System.out.print(animal.toString());
```

...should be

```
        System.out.print(temp.animal.toString());
```

As `animal` is an instance variable of `LinkNode`, not `PetList`